# Building a DLL with VC++ function is inaccessible

Tags: c++, windows, dll, header-files, dllexport

Today I needed a small library to recursively list all the files in a folder and all the subfolders. So I decided to create a small library, it is very simple and only contains two functions:

```
bool __cdecl isDir(std::string dir);
void __cdecl listDir(std::string dir, std::vector<std::string> &files, bool recursive);
```

The function of these are quiet self explanatory.

It contains one header file which defines a class `FR` and I [export](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d.aspx) that using

> __declspec( dllexport )

The reason for me bothering to do this small library is that it can be used in future projects without having to incorporate the source files into my projects all the time.

This is how I *try* to call one of the functions:

```
FR *clazz = new FR();
clazz->isDir("C:/path/to/dir");
```

And this is the error generated: 
*IntelliSense: function "FR::isDir" (declared at line 11 of "C:\dev\FileRecursionDLL\inc\fr.h") is inaccessible*

**[fr.cpp]**

```
#include "fr.h"

using namespace std;

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    return TRUE;
}

DllExport bool __cdecl FR::isDir(string dir){
    struct stat fileInfo;
    stat(dir.c_str(), &fileInfo);
    if (S_ISDIR(fileInfo.st_mode)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

DllExport void __cdecl FR::listDir(string dir, vector<string> &files, bool recursive){
    DIR *dp; //create the directory object
    struct dirent *entry; //create the entry structure
    dp = opendir(dir.c_str()); //open directory by converting the string to const char*
    if (dir.at(dir.length() - 1) != '/'){
        dir = dir + "/";
    }
    if (dp != NULL){ //if the directory isn't empty
        while (entry = readdir(dp)){ //while there is something in the directory
            if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") != 0){ //and if the entry isn't "." or ".."
                if (isDir(dir + entry->d_name) == true && recursive == true){//check if the new path is a directory, and if it is (and recursion is specified as true), recurse.
                    files.push_back(string(entry->d_name)); //add entry to the list of files
                    listDir(dir + entry->d_name, files, true); //recurse
                }
                else{
                    files.push_back(string(entry->d_name));//add the entry to the list of files
                }
            }
        }
        (void)closedir(dp); //close directory
    }
    else{
        perror("Couldn't open the directory.");
    }
}
```

**[fr.h]**

```
#ifndef FR_H
#define FR_H

#define DllExport   __declspec( dllexport ) 

#include<dirent.h>
#include<vector>

class DllExport FR
{
    bool __cdecl isDir(std::string dir);
    void __cdecl listDir(std::string dir, std::vector<std::string> &files, bool recursive);
};
#endif
```

**NOTE:** A reference to a library already doing this would also be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your methods `isDir` and `listDir` are `private` (maybe make them `public`, I suspect this the error.

Comment: @Niall Yes, that was the error, I was so close :S

Comment: @Niall Although, it threw a exception unfortunately (Unhandled exception at 0x59B414A6 (frlib.dll) in NCV Tool.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x004FE03F.), any idea what that means?

Comment: it's probably a pointer incorrectly initialised, or an out of bounds situation. A debugger should give you an idea of the location and then your call stack.

Comment: @Niall I used the debugger and it referred to this line:`if (dir.at(dir.length() - 1) != '/'){`

Comment: What is `dir`'s length?

Comment: @Niall "C:/dev/c_cpp" is the string I used, so that would be 12 characters. If that is what you mean.

Comment: I was yes. That should be fine. Maybe isolate the error further (MCVE) and possibly even post it as another question.

Comment: FWIW: note that if you export C++ classes and member functions from a DLL, only the same compiler with the same version will certainly  be able to use them. If you want to export thus that other compilers (C++, or other languages) can also use the DLL, use plain C (extern "C") functions and only pass POD types or structs or arrays of POD types back and forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class` members are `private` by default, `struct` members are `public` by default.

---

That said, why not do a general and simple to create and use header-only module instead of adding the complexity of a compiler-specific DLL.

Also, for Windows programming better use wide character strings (i.e. Unicode).

---

Example:

```
#pragma once
// Copyright (c) 2014 Alf P. Steinbach

#undef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>

#include <string>           // std::wstring
#include <vector>           // std::vector

namespace filesystem{
    using std::wstring;
    using std::vector;

    inline
    auto path_join( wstring const& a, wstring const& b )
        -> wstring
    {
        int const len_a = a.length();
        int const len_b = b.length();

        if( len_a == 0 ) { return b; }
        if( len_b == 0 ) { return a; }

        wstring result = a;
        if( a[len_a - 1] == L'\\' )
        {
            if( b[0] == L'\\' ) { result.resize( len_a - 1 ); }
        }
        else if( b[0] != L'\\' )
        {
            result += L'\\';
        }
        result += b;
        return result;
    }


    enum Recursion { no_recursion, recursive };

    inline
    auto directory_entries( wstring const& directory_path, Recursion const r = no_recursion )
        -> vector<wstring>
    {
        vector<wstring> result;
        WIN32_FIND_DATA state = {};
        HANDLE const h = FindFirstFile( path_join( directory_path, L"*.*" ).c_str(), &state );
        for(
            bool more = (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
            more;
            more = !!FindNextFile( h, &state )
            )
        {
            result.push_back( state.cFileName );
            if( r == recursive && !!(state.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) )
            {
                // TODO: Check that this isn't a "." or ".." or (hard problem) circular symlink entry.
                bool const is_true_subdirectory = false;        // <-- Here.
                if( is_true_subdirectory )
                {
                    auto const sub_entries = directory_entries(
                        path_join( directory_path, state.cFileName ), recursive
                        );
                    for( auto const& e : sub_entries )
                    {
                        result.push_back( e );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        FindClose( h );
        return result;
    }

}  // namespace filesystem
```

Comment: Because I have little knowledge about header-only modules, I know dirent.h is a self-contained header file, but I wish to create/find a extremely simple API so I can do this simply by calling one function, without having to copy and paste it into all my projects.

Comment: @Linus: okay, let me cook something up then.

Comment: Thank you very much for providing an example, I will have a look soon! :)

Comment: Do I have permission to edit your example? Or what are the terms of use? Because I noticed you made the example copyright protected.

Comment: You can just use it. You don't even have to include the copyright. It's just example code (even though it works).

Comment: Okay thank you very much, do you know what would be a good approach to deal with circular symlink entries? Is the best way just to check if the current file is not equal to "." or ".."?